# Try Throw Catch c++ nested functions

Tags: c++, exception, throw

So I declared and defined a function with the throw statement and the other function that nests the previously described function. My book says in c++ if the nested function throw data type doesn't match the catch parameter then the calling function will be terminated. However my code below doesn't do it. Instead it just skips over the exception thrown as if it wasn't even thrown in the first place. Here's the code snippet that should make what I am saying clearer.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
void setlength(double w)
{
  if (w >= 0)
  {

    cout << "We're good";
  }

  else if (w > -5 && w < 0)
  {
    string sample = "Hello";
    throw  sample;
  }
}
void setwaidth(double w)
{
  try
  {
    setlength(-3);
    cout << "OK";
  }
  catch (int a)
   {
    cout << "Error has occurred";
   }
   if (w >= 0)
   {

    cout << "We're good";
   }

   else if (w > -5 && w < 0)
   {
    string sample= "Hello";
    throw  sample;
   }
}


int main()
{
  try
   {
    setwaidth(-3);
    cout << "OK";
    }
   catch (string a)
   {
    cout << a;
   }
}
```

This just displays Hello but shouldn't this abort because -3 is in the else if statement for setlength with the data type being string but the catch has an int data type.

Comment: please provide sample input and output

Comment: Have you tried looking at your code? Run it line by line. It should display Hello

Comment: I agree wtih KRUKUSA: This ought to show "Hello". Why do you think something else? Perhaps you have your && and || confused?

Comment: Nothing gets "skipped over"! Why do people keep thinking C++ is randomly "skipping over" their code? o.O

Comment: OK so what everyone is trying to say here is that the nested function exception that is thrown will be found scrambling towards the "next" level of outer try catch blocks till it finds the according handler. I understand that. However what about the -3 for the outside function setwaidth does that not execute and gets skipped over cause if not there shoud be two hello.

Answer (score 3):

You are catching in two different places, the inner catch is in your setwaidth function. Here you catch an int. Because you are throwing a string, your exception is not caught. After that the exception travels up the call stack to your main function where a string is caught and the catch executes `cout << a;`

Furthermore if your exception to catch the string was not there the program would have terminated with an unhandled exception error which is what your book is talking about.

Answer (score 0):

> My book says in c++ if the nested function throw data type doesn't
>   match the catch parameter then the calling function will be
>   terminated.

Your book is not saying what you think it is. If a thrown exception is not caught by a calling function, then the exception goes out to the next function, and so forth.  The execution of each function like this is aborted. If it leaves your `main` function, then the program will be terminated.

Notice how the code `cout << "We're good";` was not executed? That's because the `void setwaidth(double w)` function did not continue when the exception was not caught.

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/terminate/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If a try block doesn't provide a handler for the exception type, the standard requires the "next" try block in the call stack (a surrounding try block if available) to be evaluated. Only if there isn't any catch matching the thrown type, `std::terminate()` is called.

The standard includes

> **C++11, 15.3/6**
>
> If no match is found among the handlers for a try block, the search for a matching handler continues in a dynamically surrounding try block of the same thread.
>
> **C++11, 15.3/9**
>
> If no matching handler is found, the function std::terminate() is called; whether or not the stack is unwound before this call to std::terminate() is implementation-defined.

`setwaidth(-3);` calls `setlength(-3);` throwing a `string`, catched in `main` since `setwaidth` does not catch it.